# Pegar a quebra de linha em um arquivo e colocar o conteúdo em uma variável

Tags: php

Eu estou pegando um arquivo em PHP.

```
$arquivo = file_get_contents($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name']);
```

Eu quero saber como eu faço para pegar este arquivo e colocá-lo em uma *array* para cada quebra de linha que ele encontrar **\n**.

por exemplo:

```
Nome 1
Nome 2
Nome 3
Nome 4
```

Eu irei pegar estes 4 nomes em um arquivo **.txt** e coloca-los em um *array*. O objetivo é colocar todas as informações em um vetor e escreve-las.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode usar a função [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php) para isso:

```
$nomes = explode("\n", $arquivo);
```

Caso queira somente visualizar os dados, você pode utilizar o [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.nl2br.php) ou iterar os resultados:

```
echo nl2br($arquivo);

foreach($nomes as $nome){
    echo $nome;
}
```

Comment: Como eu faço para escrever as variáveis?

Comment: Com `print_r` ou use um `foreach` para iterar os resultados. Pode também referenciar linha por linha usando o índice do *array* `$nomes[0]`

Answer (score 3):

Utilize a função [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file.php), ela lê o arquivo selecionado para um array.

```
$lines = file ('arquivo');

// Percorre o array, mostrando o número da linha que está
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    echo "Linha #<b>{$line_num+1}</b> : {$line}<br>\n";
}
```